# Ant FTP and Multiple File get (mget)

Tags: ant, ftp

Is there any way to use mget within Ant, without using the exec task?

Here is the rundown. I have to connect to a third party server that does not support globbing with FTP get, the server requires the client use mget to do a glob.

Here is my task:

```
<ftp server="host" userid="user" password="pass" action="get">
    <fileset dir="mydir">
        <include name="pdf/*_PDF.ZIP.pgp"/>
    </fileset>
</ftp>
```

It does not return any files. When I log in directly (Linux FTP command line client) I can see files. "get *" fails but "mget *" works.

Any ideas how to get Ant to use mget instead of get?

Answer (score 0):

Ant uses commons-net.jar for the FTPTask.

If you don't care about platform independence the easiest way would be to use a specific executable and the exec task. You could check in the mget.exe along with the project so the user does not need to install it.

If you need platform independence you will probably need to write you own FTP task. You could copy the one in the Ant source code and make the necessary modifications. You could also choose another FTP library if you want but I think that commons net should have the necessary features.

Comment: After more research the only obvious option is exec. I wanted to avoid that (as I stated in my original question), but I guess I have no more options. Thanks for taking the time to post a response.